# Writing to indexed file returns success but fails

Tags: input, indexing, cobol

In the following program I perform a basic interaction with an indexed file. When executed everything works as expected when I try to add a record, I even receive the success message. However when the code to read it - `lees` - tries to find the corresponding ID, it can't find it. When I look at the size of the indexed file on my disk I can see it has a size of 0kb. What am I overlooking?

```
000100 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
000200 PROGRAM-ID. oef16_indexedfiles.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT indexfile ASSIGN TO "C:\Test\indexedfile.dat"
ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
ACCESS IS DYNAMIC
RECORD KEY IS id-number
ALTERNATE KEY IS fname WITH DUPLICATES
ALTERNATE KEY IS lname WITH DUPLICATES
ALTERNATE KEY IS city WITH DUPLICATES
ALTERNATE KEY IS hobby WITH DUPLICATES.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD indexfile.
01 persoon.
 02 id-number    PIC 9.
 02 name.
        03 fname        PIC A(25).
        03 lname        PIC A(30).
 02 city         PIC A(30).
 02 hobby        PIC X(40).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 einde        PIC X.
01 msg          PIC X(50).
01 countno      PIC 9 VALUE 1.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
PGM.
 PERFORM schrijf
 PERFORM lees
 STOP RUN.

   check.
    DISPLAY msg
    ACCEPT einde

   schrijf.
   MOVE "1 = stoppen, 0 = doorgaan" TO msg       
   PERFORM check
   OPEN I-O indexfile

   PERFORM UNTIL einde = 1
    MOVE countno TO id-number

    DISPLAY "Enter your first name:"
    ACCEPT fname

    DISPLAY "Enter your last name:"
    ACCEPT lname

    DISPLAY "Enter your city:"
    ACCEPT city

    DISPLAY "Enter your hobby:"
    ACCEPT hobby

    WRITE persoon
            INVALID KEY
                    DISPLAY "ERROR WRITING: " id-number
            NOT INVALID KEY
                    DISPLAY "ID " id-number " by " fname " is added"
    END-WRITE
    ADD 1 TO countno

    PERFORM check
   END-PERFORM
   CLOSE indexfile
   MOVE 0 TO einde

   lees.
    OPEN INPUT indexfile
    MOVE 1 TO id-number
    READ indexfile 
            INVALID KEY
                    DISPLAY "Invalid key: " id-number
            NOT INVALID KEY
                    DISPLAY id-number SPACE fname SPACE lname SPACE
                            city SPACE hobby
    END-READ

    CLOSE indexfile
    MOVE 0 TO einde
    ACCEPT einde
```

Comment: We can see Windows, but what version of Cobol are you using? You have no "error checking" other than "INVALID KEY", so you don't even know if you opened your file correctly.

Comment: Just wondering why you CLOSE the file and OPEN INPUT anyway. Why not just READ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding OPTIONAL to the SELECT phrase.  Keep the OPEN I-O.

SELECT **OPTIONAL** indexfile ASSIGN TO "indexedfile.dat".

OPTIONAL will allow opening a non-existent file in preparation for first write.

Plus, follow Bill's advice; get used to checking FILE-STATUS after any OPEN (or any access for that matter).

After period terminating your paragraphs, and reformatting for FIXED form (a couple of display lines exceeded column 72), this code worked fine with OpenCOBOL once OPTIONAL was added.  Before that it fails with

libcob: File does not exist (STATUS = 35) File : 'indexedfile.dat'

Answer (score 0):

I've been pointed to the answer by someone else. In the write method (`schrijf`) you have to use the `OUTPUT` method instead of `I-O` when opening a file.

For a detailed explanation: check out the comments below!

Comment: Really? It is obviously an indexed file. Open OUTPUT will "clear" the file, not necessarily helpful. I-O should allow the full gamut of file-access verbs. There may be requirements for the initial state of the file, but since we don't know the Cobol being used, we can't tell for certain. If you use FILE-STATUS to check all accesses, you should get more information from your program about what is not happening, and why.

Comment: Agreed, OUTPUT would clear the file.  But I-O doesn't work on an empty file. Put at least 1 record in under OUTPUT and then use I-O.

Comment: Incidentally, since I am a mainframe programmer, I am curious. How does a keyed file work on a Windows machine?

Comment: OPTIONAL clause.  @mswanberg, For OpenCOBOL on Windows it relies on either Berkeley DB, or VBISAM for keyed files.  Well, OpenCOBOL actually supports EXT_FH external file handlers as well, so people can roll their own keyed file handlers.  I'm not sure what the other compilers rely on for ISAM support.

Comment: mswanberg, being a mainframer, you mean I-O doesn't work on a VSAM file which has never contained any records. Put a record on, take it off, open it I-O. See what happens.

Comment: I'm no VSAM expert... okay I know a good deal, just not everything. I just know I have programs that open I-O and if a certain error code appears, it opens it for OUTPUT and puts a seed record in.  Yeah, that record could prolly be deleted afterward.

Comment: VSAM is strange in that you have to initially load a KSDS before you can access it randomly. This is why you see code that seeds a record–in fact, you might even the file opened I-O, a check for unintialized, close and open OUTPUT, add the seed record, then close and open as I-O, and the seed record deleted. I thought at some point, though, that the Enterprise COBOL runtime added an internal check for an unintialized file, which it handled this under the covers. But it's been a long time since I played with KSDSes and COBOL. (Assembler, yes.)